# Building a Hindmarsh-Rose model into a STM32

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, stm32, raspberry-pi, signal-processing

I am wondering if it is possible to simulate Hindmarsh-Rose (HR) model on a embedded systems?

I need the output of the embedded system to match the burst/firing rate of a neuron.
what protocol could i used to simulate those bursts? like SPI, UART, DMA?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is simulatable with a computer can be simulated on an embedded system. Maybe slower than on a server rack, but, still, possible. So that answers your literal question

> I am wondering if it is possible to simulate Hindmarsh-Rose (HR) model on a embedded systems?

with a clear "yes".

> I need the output of the embedded system to match the burst/firing rate of a neuron. what protocol could i used to simulate those bursts? like SPI, UART, DMA?

That question makes no sense. "Protocol" only makes sense if you're talking to *other* systems, but you say you want to simulate a SNN on **a** embedded system, singular. If you want to link multiple of these, you'd need to start writing down your actual communication requirements, which you haven't done at all. From that you could derive things like the computational hardware you need, the type of link or bus or network between the nodes, finally per-link speeds, and then could finally boil down to a selection of options. You're trying to solve the "flying" part, before you even thought about the "crawling" part.

(And DMA is not a protocol – better research about what these things are once you've finished writing down the requirements would be in order.)

Comment: Thanks Marcus, Bit more of a background. I am trying to build a hardware based neuron into a embedded systems. So the output goes into a different hardware based neuron and see if i can integrate a controller  into it. My main concern is how to get a output from the embedded system that replicate the firing burst of a neuron?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: please put important information in your question, not just in comments under answers!

Comment: and nothing you just wrote changes anything about my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will update it tomorrow.

Comment: In that case, I'm voting to close the question for the meantime – let's vote to reopen it tomorrow, and avoid people spending time on it before you had a chance to bring it into shape.